# How to make an axios request with the respone of another axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, callback, request

// This request is responsible for getting the URL of the page that I will do web scrapping on

```
axios.post("https://async.scraperapi.com/jobs", {
   apiKey: KEY,
   url: URL,
}).then(data => {
     getThePrice(data.data.statusUrl);
 });
```

//This request is responsible for doing web scraping for the URL I got from the previous request

```
function getThePrice(scrapedURL) {
   axios.get(scrapedURL).then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

The problem is, the second request is being called before the first one has ended so I'm not getting the result I'm expecting
I tried to do the 2 requests separately by getting the link first then applying on the second one and it works but now I need to do them together

Comment: *the second request is being called before the first one has ended* - are you sure? The code doesn't suggest that

Comment: I'm sure just because I added `settimeout` for 1 second to the second request and it worked

Comment: I understood nothing. Please check the network tab in dev tools to see which request run first.

Comment: `const axios = require("axios");
(async () => {
  const { data } = await axios({
    data: {
      apiKey: KEY,
      url: "https://example.com",
    },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://async.scraperapi.com/jobs",
  });

  getHTML(data.statusUrl);
})();
async function getHTML(URL) {
  const { data } = await axios.get(URL);

  console.log(data);
}
`
this example is from scraperapi documentation and it doesn't work as well, you can sign up for an account and try it https://www.scraperapi.com/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is problem with the API itself or with network connection but this is how I would do it with async await. It is also helpful to catch the error with try catch statement so you can better understand it.

```
  const handleRequests = async () => {
try {
  const { data } = await axios.post('https://async.scraperapi.com/jobs', {
    apiKey: KEY,
    url: URL,
  })
  const { data: secondReqData } = await axios.get(data?.statusUrl)
  console.log(secondReqData)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

}